# How to calculate distance between the two mouse click in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I can use this code for getting the 3d position of a mouse click but how to get the distance between two mouse clicks.
Please can anyone help me.

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();

vector.set(
    ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1,
    - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1,
    0.5 );

vector.unproject( camera );

var dir = vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize();

var distance = - camera.position.z / dir.z;

var pos = camera.position.clone().add( dir.multiplyScalar( distance ) );
```

Comment: look at http://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Vector#Reference/Math/Vector3 `.distanceTo ( v )`

Comment: but the points are no where in the screen they will be mouse clicks.how to go along with that ...on the screen i have nothing but space.and one click of mouse counts for the starting point and the click counts for the end point.I need distance between the two.

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot.**

You cannot simply unproject a screen coordinate (2D) to world (3D) coordinate using some magic formula.

if you really need 3D coordinates of mouse clicks you have to make sure those clicks hit at least one geometry in the world and you do a raytest to find out exactly at which point the clicks hit your geometries.